# Use of X and x in probability.

Tags: probability-theory

I just came back to school and started taking mathematical probability.

It has been a while since I have studied distributions and am having trouble understanding some of the notations.

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me when to use capital X and lowercase x?

For example, I know that

$$ Pr[X=x]=p^xq^{1-x}$$

is the probability of a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution and X is a random variable where x is the value of that random variable,

but currently I am studying MLEs and expressions such as

$$ E[\hat\theta] = E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i]$$

gets me a bit confused.  I feel as though $X_i$ should be $x_i$ since

$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$

If I am wrong I apologize, but at least would like to know the convention of the use of X and x since I come from a pure math back ground and haven't studied statistics much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in probability, uppercase is used to represent a random variable and lowercase for regular variable (or constant). For example, $P(X=x)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ takes the value $x$.

For your MLE example, $X_i$ are $n$ different random variable $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$.

For $\bar{x}$, this is the mean of $n$ different values $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: So, in the case where the MLE is $\bar{X}$, that is different from the mean that I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, $\bar{X}$ is an operation on a random vector $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n).